# Seventy Aravos on Succos

Tags: halacha, sukkot, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

While listening to a shiur from Rav Heinemann, he noted a Rabbi Riff - Rav in Camden and descendant of the Netziv - who was stringent for a Hagahos Ashri which says you’re supposed to have seventy aravos. Unfortunately, I was unable to find the reasoning of this Hagahos Ashri - can anyone please locate it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for taking seventy *aravot* on Succot was to signify the additional seventy bulls which were sacrificed on the holiday (cf. [Sukka 52b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.55b.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)); such was the custom of the Sura Academy as attested to by [Natronai Gaon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natronai_ben_Hilai) ([Shaare Teshuvah §312](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30774&st=&pgnum=71)). See also Otzar HaGeonim (Sukka [ibid](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38276&st=&pgnum=196)) for additional significations. The custom was ultimately codified by Tur ([OC §651](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2778), end).

With regards to the Hagahot Ashri (Sukka 3:14), two things should be noted:

1. He does not state that one is "**supposed** to have seventy", he simply quotes the Ohr Zarua ([Hilchot Sukkah §308](https://books.google.com/books?id=85RIAQAAMAAJ&lpg=RA1-PA135&ots=ODLjxthb4o&dq=%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%20%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A2%20%D7%A4%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%94&pg=RA1-PA135#v=onepage&q&f=false)) saying "יש נוהגין" (*some are accustomed to*...).
2. The custom there mentioned is to take seventy-one *aravot*, not seventy. The idea is that the numerical value of the word 'לולב' plus an added one for each of the three other species brings the total to seventy-one, signifying the number of members of the Sanhedrin ([Great Assembly](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanhedrin)).